# Генерации сочетаний удовлетворяющие условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, производительность, комбинаторика

Требуется сгерировать все сочетания 6 из 10 без повторений из множества значений массива `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`
Сгенированные сочетания должны удовлетворять условию - любые две комбинации из сгенерированных значений должны иметь не более 4 одинаковых элементов из 6. 
Требуется написать максимально эффективный и производительный код для генерации множества. Сам код предоставить не могу, поскольку не могу представить с чего начать. Подход сгенерировать, а потом отфильтровать не рассматривается. Эту тему я отдельно обсуждаю в ветке 
('[Оптимизация кода. Удаление "похожих" строк с использованием DataFrame](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997866/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-dataframe/998500#998500)').

Например:

```
Допустимо. 
1) Кол-во одинаковых элементов - 2 [5,6] для 1 и 2 строки 
2) Кол-во одинаковых элементов для 4[1,3,5,6] для 1 и 3 строки 
3) Кол-во одинаковых элементов для 4[5,6,7,8] для 2 и 3 строки

[1,2,3,4,5,6]     
[5,6,7,8,9,10]
[1,3,5,6,7,8]

Недопустимо. Кол-во одинаковых элементов - 5 [1,2,3,4,5]  
[1,2,3,4,5,6]     
[1,2,3,4,5,7] - сгенерированную запись не включать список, поскольку не удовлетворяет условиям.
```

Пример ожидаемого результата

```
     0  1  2  3  4   5
0    1  2  3  4  5   6
9    1  2  3  4  7   8
14   1  2  3  4  9  10
20   1  2  3  5  7   9
23   1  2  3  5  8  10
27   1  2  3  6  7  10
28   1  2  3  6  8   9
41   1  2  4  5  7  10
42   1  2  4  5  8   9
46   1  2  4  6  7   9
49   1  2  4  6  8  10
55   1  2  5  6  7   8
60   1  2  5  6  9  10
69   1  2  7  8  9  10
182  3  4  5  6  7   8
187  3  4  5  6  9  10
196  3  4  7  8  9  10
209  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

Comment: А что вы уже попробовали и почему решили, что оно не достаточно производительно?

Comment: Можно сгенерировать все комбинации и потом удалять похожие используя (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997866/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-dataframe/998500#998500), но меня интересует, можно ли исключать "похожие" записи на этапе генерации или возможно есть другие более красивые решения.

Comment: Не понял. В условии сказано "**любые** две комбинации из сгенерированных значений". В примере же как будто анализируются только **соседние** сгенерированные пары.

Comment: Взял соседние для наглядности.  К примеру [1,2,3,4,5,6] и [2,3,4,5,6,7] - второе значние попадает под удаление из списка

Comment: Ответ даёт эффективный путь для генерации комбинаций с заданными свойствами. Он непонятен?

Comment: @MBo - не понял вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сочетаний 6 из 10 всего 210 штук, так что не составляет никакого труда генерировать сочетания ([откуда взял](https://habr.com/ru/post/272707/)), проверять на пересечение с уже имеющимися, и заносить в список, если пересечений более 4 элементов нет

```
def next_comb(c):
    cand = c & -c
    cp = c + cand
    cxor = cp ^ c
    cand <<= 2
    cxor //= cand
    return cxor | cp

def CountBits(n):
  n = (n & 0x5555) + ((n & 0xAAAA) >> 1)
  n = (n & 0x3333) + ((n & 0xCCCC) >> 2)
  n = (n & 0x0F0F) + ((n & 0xF0F0) >> 4)
  n = (n & 0x00FF) + ((n & 0xFF00) >> 8)
  return n

c = 63
lst = [c]
n = next_comb(c)
while n <= (c << 4):
    check = True
    for i in lst:
        if CountBits(n & i) > 4:
            check = False
            break
    if check:
        lst.append(n)
    n = next_comb(n)
for i in lst:
    #print(format(i, "010b"))
    res = [(j+1) for j in range(10) if (i & (1 << j))]
    print(res)
```

Вот все результаты

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Они же в бинарном виде (единичный бит на k-й позиции означает, что соответствующее число k есть в сочетании)

```
0000111111    (1,2,3,4,5,6)
0011001111 
0011110011    (1,2,5,6,7,8)  
0011111100
0101010111
0101101011
0110011011
0110100111
1001011011
1001100111
1010010111
1010101011
1100001111
1100110011
1100111100
1111000011
1111001100
1111110000
```

Это не единственный набор. 
Если построить граф из 210 вершин, и провести ребра между сочетаниями, имеющими 5 пересекающихся элементов, то решением задачи будет любое [независимое множество вершин](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5) (Independent set).

Comment: посмотри ссылку - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/997866/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-dataframe/998500#998500

Comment: Хм. А зачем мне эта ссылка? Вопрос о генерации определенных сочетаний задан здесь. На него я и отвечал. Ответ генерирует  все сочетания согласно условию.

Comment: Твои решения  непонятны. Привел пример ожидаемого результата.

Comment: Что ж, раз с битами трудно, смотрите в виде списка.

Comment: как добавить, чтобы комбинации генерировались в случайном порядке?  К слову, чтобы стартовая комбинация была не 0000111111 а 1100111100 ? И последующие комбинации тоже были бы случайными, но при этом выполнялось условие на уникальность записи в рамках списка? Возможно ли будет сгенерировать 5 из 30 с 4 не повторяющимися элементами за 1 минуту?

Comment: Как я писал, комбинаций 6 из 10 всего 210. Их нужно сгенерировать все, сложить в список и перемешать. Далее сделать выбор совместимых комбинаций, обходя перемешанный список. 5 из 30 будет уже 142 тыс., времени уйдёт побольше, но, думаю, несколько секунд хватит.

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно понял:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import random

items = list(range(1, 11))

def split(items):
    random.shuffle(items)
    a, b = items[:5], items[5:]
    t = random.choice(b)
    b.append(random.choice(a))
    a.append(t)
    return a, b

start_time = timer()
a, b = split(items)

print(timer() - start_time)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Результат:

```
7.064198143780231e-05
[2, 1, 3, 9, 10, 6]
[7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 10]
```

Comment: скрипт должен вернуть все возможные сочетания  6 из 10 без повторений из множества значений массива [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]